# Vertices reachable by paths of length n

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given an undirected graph G = (V, E) and a vertex s, find all vertices which are reachable from s by **paths of length n**, where n is a given natural number.

There are two other versions of the problem which can be solved efficiently. One is about finding vertices whose **distance** from s is n or n at most. For this version, a bfs would be sufficient. Another version has to do with **walks** of length n, meaning that you can cross the same vertex more than once. This can be solved by calculating $A^n$, where A is the adjacency matrix. Both of these versions are different from the above problem.

Is there an efficient algorithm for this version of the problem? Vertices reachable by paths of length n are a subset of those whose distance is at most n, so a bfs could do for a start. However, after that, most things I can come up with are pretty close to brute force. Any ideas?

Comment: During BFS just re-add already visited vertices back. And you get an $n \cdot (|V| + |E|)$ complexity

Comment: I think this results in walks instead of paths.

Comment: In the case when $n=|V|-1$, an answer to this problem would solve the NP-complete [Hamilton path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem), so we shouldn't expect too much.